# Android service loses Internet connection

Tags: android, service, connection

I've developed an application to frequently send data to the Internet through HttpPost. The app is divided into 2 parts:

1) a service that is running infinitely,
2) an activity when a user can set up some data-connected stuff.

The service properties:

1) running as a foreground service,
2) involves a WakeLock (with flag PARTIAL_WAKE_LOC set up).

The activity connects to the service and when a user chooses "Start" button (after setting some specific options) it's supposed to send data to the server every 10 seconds. If the user doesn't "click" the button and taps Back instead, the activity is finished and so is the service. Howewer, after chosing "Start", the service is started (startService() is called), which means it doesn't destroy after the activity and runs continuously, until the user chooses "Stop", that calls stopService().

The solution works pretty well, but depending on the phone model it sometimes stops sending anything after a few hours of working, since the data transfer dies. Even the browser can't show any page. Sometimes switching "Use packet data" on and off helps, but more often doesn't. Rebooting the phone always solves the problem. The most strange thing is that the browser can work all day without any interruption. I've prepared a special page with JS code that forces the browser to request some data every 10 seconds (with AJAX) and it works perfectly for many many hours. When I start my app, it sends data for, let's say, 2-3 hours without any problem, and suddenly the Internet connection is off.

I have no idea what causes these problems. Any help would be appreciated. I don't show the code since it's very long.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

The device causing the problems is Samsung Galaxy Pocket GT-S5300 with Android 2.3.6 (kernel version 2.6.35.7).